# Getting "Automation error" while updating a column through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, oracle

I have written a VBA code to update a column but getting `Automation Error` while running the program at line 41 which  is `Set rsf = cmd.Execute`. Is the way of writing update statement incorrect in my code? Not getting what is the issue here. I'd appreciate any help towards a solution for my problem.

```
Private Sub Update_Visibility_Flag_Click()

Dim fldrpath As String
Dim currDate As String
Dim mePrgTrck As String
Dim wkb1 As Workbook
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim cnf As ADODB.Connection
Dim rsf As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sqlstr As String



fldrpath = "\\lp99dfd\groups$\Record Extracts\New folder\New folder\" & Format(Date, "yyyymm")
currDate = "PI_202008" 
mePrgTrck = fldrpath & "\LE\Progress_Tracker_" & Format(Date, "yyyymm") & "_LE.xlsx"

Set wkb1 = Workbooks.Open(mePrgTrck)
Set sht1 = wkb1.Sheets(currDate)

Set cnf = New ADODB.Connection
Set rsf = New ADODB.Recordset

cnf.Open ( _
        "User ID=AI_ZK_DTA" & _
        ";Password=aizkdta" & _
        ";Data Source=POIUY" & _
        ";Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle")
                


For Each cell In sht1.Range("A2:A28")
    If cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Success" Then
        sqlstr = "UPDATE AI_" & cell.Value & "_DTA SET VISIBLE = 'Y'"
        Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
        Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
        Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cnf
        cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
        cmd.Properties("PLSQLRSet") = True
        cmd.CommandText = sqlstr
        Set rsf = cmd.Execute
        cmd.Properties("PLSQLRSet") = False
        cell.Offset(0, 8).Value = cell.Offset(0, 8).Value & "| Done"
    End If
Next cell

wkb1.Close True
Set rsf = Nothing
Set cnf = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image: Automation error]

Comment: `cmd.Properties("PLSQLRSet") = True` is used when you run a **SELECT** and return a Cursor. Maybe check this example: https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/example-of-sql-insert-update-using-adodb-command-and-adodb-parameters-objects.219149/

Comment: Or have a look at this example: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51173_01/win.122/e18594/using.htm#OLEDB177